# What data will be lost if aws t1.micro instance is rebooted?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I currently have a t1.micro (free) instance running in aws, with Windows 2008 R2. I was taking a trial, getting a grasp of how to work with amazon aws service with this instance.

Now, I want to migrate it to a higher config instance say m1.large.

While I was trying to create AMI of the instance, it said that the instance is going to be rebooted, What data will I loose if the instance is rebooted ? Will the applications installed (MySql, Crystal Reports and some other apps) be deleted ?

How to migrate it without loosing any data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have a standard t1.micro with a 8 GB root volume, nothing should be lost. You would only loose data if you use [Instance Storage](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html), but you are probably not using it, unless you added it yourself.

If you really don't want to take any risk, you can select the "No Reboot" option when creating an AMI. Then try launching a new, larger instance from that AMI (while leaving the other instance running) and see for yourself.